# Displaying imageView near the LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a picture near a `LinearLayout`. I want to make the following:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
|textView1       +------------+                     |
|button1         |imageView1  |                     |
|                |            |                     |
|                |            |                     |
|                |            |                     |
|                +------------+                     |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

But with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I probably get something like that (I don't see the picture):

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
|textView1                                          |
|button1                                            |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
 imageView1
```

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the RelativeLayout to manage this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture" />
```

Now everything is on the top screen. Try to setup everything as you like.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Are you sure there isn't any way to do this with a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: There is, but instand of 1 layout view you will get 2/3. Just change orientation of one of your LinearLayout Horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

**LinearLayout** put views either in *vertical* or *horizontal* order. You need to use **RelativeLayout** to achieve this.

Set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your *ImageView* when using *RelativeLayout* and it will do the magic

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture" 
    android:totheRightof=android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:marginLeft="20dp"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `android:totheRightof=android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"` should do. Currently it gives an error and I couldn't find anything like this `totheRightof` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your `ImageView` within the Layout to achieve what you want..

Try this XML file instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So here you tell Android that you want the `ImageView` to be a part of `LinearLayout`, ofcourse you can do better if you use a `RelativeLayout`, but this was a solution to your problem.

EDIT:

If you want to use Relative Layout to achieve the same then here is the way..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code displays everything in one narrow column, that's not what I needed. `RelativeLayout` seems to be the most appropriate solution.